# How to get notified when view or its children are invalidated

Tags: android, screensharing

For a screen-sharing application, I need to perform some function whenever something on Activity's view changes. The view can be a layout having children. The change could be clicking on a button, entering text in EditText or a dialog appearing. I can't subclass the view since the program can receive any View at runtime.
I wanted to know if there is a way to get notified whenever the OS  redraws the screen.

Things I've tried:

- Setting TreeViewObserver listeners: This doesn't work for Context menu, change text in EditText
- I also looked into the source code of android View. Although, it implements Drawable.Callback, it doesn't propagate the event notification
- getClipsBound doesn't work either

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own view which will extends from View(TextVuew, EditText etc). Then you can overwrite function you need (probably invalidate). Just call function of super and add some alert implementation. It can be your own callBack or you can send from there intent to your BrodcastReciver. So you will always know when this function calls by system.

Comment: Yes I've thought of this. The problem is the module I'm developing is going to be a library which others will use while developing their own applications. This approach will require them to always use my custom view instead of normal View.